# Sorting is not working in ngTable when using nested json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, sorting, ngtable

I have created an application in angularjs with ngTable, The application is working fine but sorting is not working. My json structured is nested, but values are coming correctly with the table

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

My code is as given below

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gavxvLxe/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
    <table border="1" ng-table="mytable">
         <tbody ng-repeat="peop in peoples">
        <tr ng-repeat="people in peop">
            <td sortable="'id'" data-title="'Id'">{{people.id}}</td>
            <td sortable="'desig'" data-title="'Desig'">{{people.desig}}</td>
            <td sortable="'name'" data-title="'Name'">{{people.name}}</td>
            <td sortable="'place'" data-title="'Place'">{{people.place}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('IndexCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
  $scope.peoples = {
    "ime123": [{"id": 145, 
                "desig": "doctor",
                "name": "Manu",
                "place": "ABCD"
               }],
    "ime148": [{"id": 148,
                "desig": "engineer",
                "name": "John",
                "place": "POLK"
               },
               {
                "id": 150,
                "desig": "scientist",
                "name": "Mary",
                "place": "USE"
               }]
  };    
        $scope.mytable = new ngTableParams({
        sorting: {
            name: 'desc'
        }
    }, {
        getData: function($defer, params) {
        $scope.peoples = $filter('orderBy')( $scope.peoples, params.orderBy());
        $defer.resolve( $scope.peoples);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/esvit/ng-table/master/ng-table.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. - refusing to execute script in your fiddle,can you fix it first?

Comment: your working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gavxvLxe/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The way you work with nested array in [ngtable](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/13) is not suitable ,in your case you can make array one dim again and allow directive to groupping

#### html

```
<table border="1" ng-table="mytable">
        <tbody ng-repeat="peop in $groups">
            <tr ng-repeat="people in peop.data">
                <td sortable="id" data-title="'Id'">{{people.id}}</td>
                <td sortable="desig" data-title="'Desig'">{{people.desig}}</td>
                <td sortable="name" data-title="'Name'">{{people.name}}</td>
                <td sortable="place" data-title="'Place'">{{people.place}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

#### contoller

```
$scope.mytable = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10,          // count per page
        sorting: {
            name: 'desc'
        }
    }, {
        total: peoples.length,
        groupBy:'group',
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            peoples = $filter('orderBy')(peoples, params.orderBy());
            $defer.resolve(peoples);
        }
    });
```

#### data

```
var peoples = [{
        "id": 145,
            "desig": "doctor",
            "name": "Manu",
            "place": "ABCD",
            "group": "ime123"  //for grouping
    }, {
        "id": 148,
            "desig": "engineer",
            "name": "John",
            "place": "POLK",
            "group": "ime148" //for grouping
    }, {
        "id": 150,
            "desig": "scientist",
            "name": "Mary",
            "place": "USE",
            "group": "ime148"  //for grouping
    }];
```

here almost working  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gavxvLxe/5/).
default desc not working yet (ver 0.3.1)