# ngtable : sort and filter on nested object

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have a list of objects to display on a table with ngTable.
My object looks like :

```
obj {label:string,
     nestObj{nestLabel:string
            }
    }
```

In my controller I want to allow sorting and filtering on fields 'label' and 'nestObject.label'. I have tried this:

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10,
        filter: {
            label='',
            nestObj.label=''
        },
        sorting: {
            label: 'asc',
            nestObj.label: 'asc'
        }
    }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            // use build-in angular filter
            var filteredData = params.filter() ?
            $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) :
            data;
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                    $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                    data;

            params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }          
});
```

But I m getting an error, the javascript compiler doesn't like the filter on nestObj.label :

> Uncaugth syntexError : unexpected token .

IT works well if I don't filter and sort on nestObj.label.

Is it possible to filter and sort on nested object with ngTable?

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8aawdF9zzpNKnS4WJFOt?p=preview) that illustrate the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide us plunker or jsfiddle..?

Comment: I added the plunkr in the main message

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, the filtering and sorting with nested objects is not suitable in ng-table for now. Reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649205/sorting-is-not-working-in-ngtable-when-using-nested-json) and solution from @[Kostia Mololkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4104866/kostia-mololkin), I finally got it how to avoid this bug and the solution is in the end very simple. Big thanks to him!

I just rewrote the array where is your data: initialized the new property and set the data from nested object into the new property like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i].town = ""; //initialization of new property 
  data[i].town = data[i].adresse.town;  //set the data from nested obj into new property
}
```

You can see this solution here on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D11qLHlnsJtrAFLPs4Lj?p=preview),
 now it's working like a charm...

Comment: I deleted my previous answer because I was on the completely wrong way to solve it. Hope that's it! :)

Comment: If you are satisfied with this solution, you could also accept my answer :) I'm glad that I helped.

Comment: It seems, that now at least filtering for nested properties is supported http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-nested-property, can't say for sure about sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my two cents as I came across, don't be afraid to make use of functional programming.  Flattening data is simple and in my opinion cleaner like so:

```
var flattenedArray = dataArray.map(function(obj) {
    return {
        label: obj.label,
        nestedLabel: dataItem.nestedObj.nestedLabel
    };
});
```

Then you can sort by `label` and `nestedLabel` in ngTable with ease.

*Note: I realize we are making copies here so a little more memory is consumed.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `getData` method to support nested params and additional support for ordering and paging. Need to inject `$filter` and rename `myData` with your own array of datas. Hope it can help.

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({},
{
    getData: function($defer, params) {

        // organize filter as $filter understand it (graph object)
        var filters = {};
        angular.forEach(params.filter(), function(val,key){
            var filter = filters;
            var parts = key.split('.');
            for (var i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
                if (i!=parts.length-1) {
                    filter[parts[i]] = {};
                    filter = filter[parts[i]];
                }
                else {
                    filter[parts[i]] = val;
                }
            }
        })

        // filter with $filter (don't forget to inject it)
        var filteredDatas =
            params.filter() ?
                $filter('filter')(myDatas, filters) :
                myDatas;

        // ordering
        var sorting = params.sorting();
        var key = sorting ? Object.keys(sorting)[0] : null;
        var orderedDatas = sorting ? $filter('orderBy')(filteredDatas, key, sorting[key] == 'desc') : filteredDatas;

        // get for the wanted subset
        var splitedDatas =
            orderedDatas.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(),
                params.page() * params.count());

        params.total(splitedDatas.length);

        // resolve the ngTable promise
        $defer.resolve(splitedDatas);
    }
});
```