# ng-table not show the filter when this fields are from the fields that are nested

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

First, I'm working with `ng-table`. The problem is that isn't showing the filter when this fields are from the fields that are nested. I wanna to filter by field name of user or field title of event. this is my json field:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date_in": "2016-06-15 09:07:20",
    "date_out": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "event_id": 1,
    "event": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Programaci",
      "authorize": "pending",
      "user_id": 1,
      "room_id": 1,
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "andres",
        "email": "andres@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "date_in": "2016-06-15 10:07:20",
    "date_out": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "event_id": 1,
    "event": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "tecnology",
      "authorize": "pending",
      "user_id": 1,
      "room_id": 1,
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "peter",
        "email": "andres@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You can see my complete code [**here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/XeUrJEmbdFy1IIQOa9kg?p=preview).

Comment: I recommend you to check another module, like Smart Table, Ui grid or something like this. There are a lot of problems with `ngTable`. Also you should do some tricks to make it work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959776/ngtable-sort-and-filter-on-nested-object/#answer-27976264

Comment: Thanks @developer033