# Angularjs - ngTable : get filter values

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have a ngTable in my view.
How, in my controller, can I get the filter values of my ngTable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-table : filter on column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333148/ng-table-filter-on-column)

Comment: nope, here I want to get what are the filters applied by the user. (on what property and what value)

Comment: Could be useful: http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-api

Comment: Or listen to the event "afterReloadData" http://ng-table.com/#/events/demo-subscribe

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.dataTable = new NgTableParams({}, {dataset: $scope.data_list});
var filterValues = $scope.dataTable.filter();
```

You can use filter() method of table, like above.